# what happen when we delete resolv.conf file from a linux server

Tags: linux, unix

I have deleted the resolv.conf file from Linux server and now I am not able to login to the server. What is the logic behind this and How can this be resolved ??

Comment: What error messages do you get?

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/resolv.conf.5.html

Comment: I up voted. While this is a noob question, it's a reasonable one and it's being asked by a new user to the site. Being locked out of a server because of a mistake you make is a good reason to ask for help.

Comment: Are you getting an error message? If not, how long are you waiting before you're deciding that you are not able to log in? Do wait several minutes!

Comment: What OS is running on that Linux server? How is its network configured? fixed IP or dhcp? Is the account you use local or from a distributed base (e.g. NIS, LDAP, AD)? How do you try to log in? (ssh, console, ...)? Why did you deleted the resolv.conf file?

Answer (score 2):

**It should not be needed**, especially for a console login. But if necessary you can boot Linux into single user mode or init=/bin/bash, rescue disk, etc... and recreate the file. If it's a VM and you don't have console access then you can mount the volume on another working VM in some cases (like AWS).

I wanted to see, so just now I removed `resolv.conf` on one of my systems (Ubuntu 16.04) and ssh'd into it. **Everything worked fine.**

I suspect you have something else going on if you can't do a console or ssh login. If it is just the resolv.conf, it's not a big deal and is easy to fix.

A basic `resolv.conf` looks like this (in case you needed help):

```
nameserver x.x.x.x
```

x.x.x.x = IP of your name server. You can use 8.8.8.8 if you need a public name server and don't know what to put in there.

Answer (score -1):

If you use ssh the sshd will do a reverse loop for an incoming IP-address. You can use "UseDNS no" inside sshd_config to avoid this. In general "resolv.conf" is used to "translate" ip addresses to names. you should restore resolv.conf because many programs need to do such lookups.

Comment: This shouldn't stop you logging in, all it does is slow down your login.